# Como puedo pegar en emacs algo copiado desde Google chrome?

Tags: html5, google-chrome, emacs

Quisiera saber como pegar en emacs una dirección que he copiado desde google chrome, se me hace muy agotador tener que escribirla completa y quisiera saber si hay una forma mas sencilla de hacer esto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con la combinación de teclas `C-y` (Control y)
También lo puedes hacer con Shift-Insert

Aquí hay algunos comandos básicos de emacs.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf

Por acá hay otros mas.
https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/emacs.html